# SQL Server 2008 Split String From Field In Record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data set that looks like the below (the input).

```
IR#   CR#
1     1,2
2     3
3     4,5,6
```

I would like the following output. You can consider all fields varchar for this example.

```
IR#   CR#
1     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
3     5
3     6
```

I have UDFs to split a CSV string into rows...but not something to split 1 row in a table into multiple rows and then union will the next row, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) in conjunction with your splitting UDF. The string splitter I'm using for my example comes from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1665).

```
/* Create function for purposes of demo */
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseStringTSQL] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX),@separator NCHAR(1))
RETURNS @parsedString TABLE (string NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @position int
   SET @position = 1
   SET @string = @string + @separator
   WHILE charindex(@separator,@string,@position) <> 0
      BEGIN
         INSERT into @parsedString
         SELECT substring(@string, @position, charindex(@separator,@string,@position) - @position)
         SET @position = charindex(@separator,@string,@position) + 1
      END
     RETURN
END
go

/* Set up sample data */
declare @t table (
    IR int,
    CR varchar(100)
)

insert into @t
    (IR, CR)
    select 1, '1,2' union all
    select 2, '3' union all
    select 3, '4,5,6'

/* Here's the query that solves the problem */
select t.IR, p.string
    from @t t
        cross apply [dbo].[fnParseStringTSQL](t.CR,',') p


/* clean up after demo */
drop function [dbo].[fnParseStringTSQL]
```

Comment: Of course this should only be done to transform the data into a relational model not to use continually on badly-formed data.  The need to do this indicates the need to urgently redesign.