# how to update an table column name from the values in the same table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
  eid   |        ename          |    fname       midname  |   lname
--------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+---------- 
   1            hansen
   2          hansen ola
   3       dennis richard hog
```

Now how to update them to be like this:

```
  eid   |        ename          |    fname       midname  |   lname
--------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+---------- 
   1             hansen
   2           hansen ola            hansen        ola
   3       dennis richsard hog       dennis      richard       hog
```

Comment: Which database software you are using?

Comment: @user1500707, It's not good idea, You can design your database straight forward as you want.

Comment: It seems you will have to write a function for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649229/sql-server-2008-split-string-from-field-in-record

Comment: What if you have an Ename with more than 3 names?

Comment: What is the logic? I see that 1st row doesn't have anything in fname. Why? Consider changing the title. It sounds like you want to ALTER the COLUMN name (DDL).

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `ename` from the table and break it up into firstname, middlename and lastname using `explode(' ', $name)` or `str_word_count ($name, 1)` and update the table accordingly.

SQL for selecting rows:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename>
```

SQL for updating rows:

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <columnname> = <value> WHERE ename = <ename>
```

Comment: The OP wants to Update the columns `fname, midname,  lname` from the column `ename` by splitting it into these three columns.

Comment: @AbhishekDas User has not tagged this question in php.

Comment: want to notice the space between the ename and then want to update int fname , midname , lnmae

Answer (score 0):

If the names are always in the same order, you can simply retrieve the words of a string in an array with [**`str_word_count`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php): `str_word_count ($ result, 1)`.

It helps you or you want me to develop?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check this SQL code below for the updates statement.

```
CREATE TABLE emptble(eid int,ename varchar(200) NULL,fname varchar(50) NULL,midname varchar(25) NULL,lname varchar(100) NULL)

INSERT INTO emptble(eid,ename)
VALUES(1,'hansen'),(2,'hansen ola'),(3,'dennis richard hog')

SELECT ename,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)>0 then LEFT(ename,CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)-1) ELSE ename END,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)>0 THEN LEFT((CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)-1) ELSE (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END) END,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE RIGHT(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END,LEN(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END)-CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)) END


FROM emptble

UPDATE emptble SET fname= CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)>0 then LEFT(ename,CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)-1) ELSE ename END,
                   midname =CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)>0 THEN LEFT((CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)-1) ELSE (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END) END,
                   lname=CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE RIGHT(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END,LEN(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END)-CHARINDEX(' ',(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1) = 0 then NULL ELSE RIGHT(ename,len(ename)-CHARINDEX(' ',ename,1)) END),1)) END



SELECT * FROM emptble
```